# what's the difference between two methods Show and ShowWithPath

Tags: unity-game-engine, everyplay

Can anyone explain me in details that what's the difference between two methods  Everyplay.SharedInstance.Show() and Everyplay.SharedInstance.ShowWithPath("/feed/game")

Additionally in second method are we suppose to replace game in "/feed/game" with th ename of our game.

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Show() method will always show the logged-in users "Following" feed. If the user is not logged in, then they will be shown the current game feed. To force showing of the game feed always, use ShowWithPath("/feed/game"); as that will always default to the current game.